# Speed up applying a transformation to each index value of a given array

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I need to apply a function to the result of a transformation of all index values of a given numpy array. The following code does this:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform

# some 2D array
a = np.empty((2,3))
# some affine transformation, identity is just an example here
trans = IdentityTransform()
# some function taking a 2D index and returning some value depending
# on that index, again just an example
def f(idx):
    return (idx[0]+idx[1])/2
# apply f to the result of transforming each index of a
b=np.empty_like(a)
for idx in np.ndindex(a.shape):
    b[idx] = f(trans.transform(idx))
print(b)
```

This prints the following correct result:

> [[0.  0.5 1. ]
> [0.5 1.  1.5]]

The problem now is, the code is too slow when the shape of `a` gets larger, say 2000x3000. Is there a way to speed this up?

My idea is to create an array of indices of a `idx = [[0,0], [0,1], ..., [1,2]]`, then transform this array in one go using something like `tmp = trans.transform(idx)`, and lastly apply `f` to every element with `np.vectorize(f)(tmp)`.

Is this a reasonable approach? If yes, how would this actually look like? If no, are there any alternatives?

Edit: I managed to get at `tmp` via the following code:

```py
tmp=trans.transform(np.asarray([idx for idx in np.ndindex(a.shape)]))
```

So now I have an array containing the results of the affine transformation for every index value of `a`. But this seems to use an awful lot of memory.

Comment: `(np.arange(a.shape[1]) + np.arange(a.shape[0])[...,None])/2`?

Comment: That said, you should think how to vectorize your function. For a general *some function*, you are almost at your best bet.`np.vectorize` is just a for loop, so you wouldn't get much improvement from the current code. Maybe, `numba` can help you on speeding up the for loop there.

Comment: @QuangHoang I think you missed the transformation part. As I most likely cannot vectorize `f` (but I indeed need to think on that), is there at least some fast way of getting at `tmp` in the question?

Comment: I can't tell you if there is anything. Your `trans` is just identity, so it does nothing. AFAIK, matplotlib transformations are affine, so they should be vectorized already. If not, it should be possible to write a vectorize version. The vectorized version for `np.nindex` would be `np.meshgrid`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an answer myself with what I figured out now. Maybe it is of use for someone.

To answer the first part of my question, I found a fast and efficient way to create the result of transforming the index values, using the result of `np.indices()` and then massaging the result of that until it fits to what `t.transform()` expects.

Given some array `a = np.empty((2,3))`, the indices of that array can be obtained via `np.indices(a.shape)`. This returns two 2D arrays (one for each dimension of `a`, actually). What I failed to understand was how to turn these results into something `transform()` understands.

The key here is to apply `np.ravel()` to the result of each of those arrays, `np.indices()` returns:

```py
>>> a=np.empty((2,3))
>>> list(map(np.ravel, np.indices(a.shape)))
[array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])]
```

Now I have a list of arrays containing all the x and y indices, which just needs to be put together with `np.vstack()` and then transposed to get an array of all (x, y) indices, and this is the form `transform()` will accept.

```py
>>> l=list(map(np.ravel, np.indices(a.shape)))
>>> np.vstack(l).transpose()
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

And finally, for some arbitrary affine transformation:

```py
>>> from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
>>> t = Affine2D().translate(10, 20).scale(0.5)
>>> t.transform(np.vstack(l).transpose())
array([[ 5. , 10. ],
       [ 5. , 10.5],
       [ 5. , 11. ],
       [ 5.5, 10. ],
       [ 5.5, 10.5],
       [ 5.5, 11. ]])
```

This is quite fast, even for larger array sizes. If the shape gets big enough (something like 20000x30000), I run out of memory, but for shapes 10000x10000 it still is amazingly fast.

```py
>>> timeit.timeit("t.transform(np.vstack(list(map(np.ravel, np.indices(a.shape, dtype=np.uint16)))).transpose())",
...    "import numpy as np ; from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D ; a = np.empty((20, 10)) ; t = Affine2D().translate(10, 20).scale(0.5)", number=10)
0.0003051299718208611
>>> timeit.timeit("t.transform(np.vstack(list(map(np.ravel, np.indices(a.shape, dtype=np.uint16)))).transpose())",
...    "import numpy as np ; from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D ; a = np.empty((200, 100)) ; t = Affine2D().translate(10, 20).scale(0.5)", number=10)
0.0026413939776830375
>>> timeit.timeit("t.transform(np.vstack(list(map(np.ravel, np.indices(a.shape, dtype=np.uint16)))).transpose())",
...    "import numpy as np ; from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D ; a = np.empty((2000, 1000)) ; t = Affine2D().translate(10, 20).scale(0.5)", number=10)
0.35055489401565865
>>> timeit.timeit("t.transform(np.vstack(list(map(np.ravel, np.indices(a.shape, dtype=np.uint16)))).transpose())",
...    "import numpy as np ; from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D ; a = np.empty((20000, 10000)) ; t = Affine2D().translate(10, 20).scale(0.5)", number=10)
43.62860555597581
```

Now for the second part, for applying the function to each of the transformed index values I use the following code for now, which is fast enough in my case.

```py
xxyy = t.transform(np.vstack(...).transpose())
np.fromiter((f(*xy) for xy in xxyy), dtype=np.short, count=len(xxyy))
```